# How Armature reaction is different from Self inductance?

Tags: generator, inductance, synchronous, self-induction

It was given in "Electric machinery Fundamentals" by Stephen J. Chapman book that Armature reaction and self inductance is different. Contribution from armature reaction is considered as voltage drop \$jXI_{A}\$, with reasoning that \$B_{stator}\$ produced by current through stator coils would induce voltage \$E_{stator}\$. Later as shown in the image attached, net reactance is taken as \$ X + X_{A}\$, \$X_{A}\$ being self inductance. What I don't undertsand is, how armature reactaion is different from self inductance ?

[image: attached image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are talking about alternators (synchronous generators).

The self-inductance is due to physics of the winding itself and is equal to N^2/Reluctance, where N is nymber of turns of the winding.

However, armature reaction is due to current flowing through the armature winding. It gives rise to magnetic field which distorts the main magnetic field.(the one which is responsible for inducing emf that causes current in the armature winding)

You can remove stator winding from alternator and supply it externally with ac source, then you will find that it has inductance only equal to its self-inductance.

However inside the alternator, while loaded, the demagnetizing effect of armature reaction, *actually* decreases resultant amp-turns(mmf). And hence terminal voltage of alternator decreases. The demagnetizing effect of armature reaction is represented by an equivalent reactance called "Armature Reaction Reactance", which is different from self-inductive reactance possessed by winding due to it's physical properties viz. length, area of cross section, no. of turns and material.